# php mysql checkbox save inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have this loop for list rows, what I want to do is return to base 1 or 0 (1 check, 0 uncheck) to that row that is listed. I manage to do this without the WHILE function, but in while function it won't work.

```
<?php

    $interval = $conn->query("SELECT ID,Vrsta_segmenta, Active FROM `msa_segmenti`");
    if ($interval->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $interval->fetch_array()) {
            $checked =  $row["Active"]; 
    ?>                              
    <form name="update" method="POST" action="msa_pauze_admin.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><?php echo $row["Vrsta_segmenta"];?></label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <div class="">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $row["Active"];?>" class="js-switch" 
                        <?php
                        if ($checked == '1') { ?> checked
                        <?php
                        } else if ($checked == '0')  "" 
                        ?>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php  }} ?>              
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">Save</button>
```

Now i need to return value to the db when i click save button.
I know i need to check click state so i try this but did not work:

```
if (isset($_POST["check"])) {
    $check_value == '1';
    $interval_check_save = "UPDATE `msa_segmenti` SET `Active` = '".$check_value."' WHERE `ID` = '".$id."'";
    $mysqli->query($interval_check_save);
} else {
    $check_value == '0';
    $interval_check_save = "UPDATE `msa_segmenti` SET `Active` = '".$check_value."' WHERE `ID` = '".$id."'";
    $mysqli->query($interval_check_save);

}
```

Comment: Look into source code what HTML is rendered.

Comment: i can read from database, but the problem is when i need to save changed state

Comment: If you are unchecked, you will not get any value, so check the post data and write the code to match the behaviour, probably you will get null,if unchecked.

Comment: @rtstorm: Ah, okay, problem is with saving. You try to save `$_POST['check']` which is the last one checkbox. Change checkboxes names to `check[]`, then values will be in array `$_POST['check']`. Plus change `==` into `=` in saving script.

Comment: @panther: i add [] in input name and change == to = but still no save is done. :( 
I noticed that if i manual chenge from 1 to 0 in db and when i refresh the page it will change to 1. So i think script is beeing called regard ISSET. Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem:

```
<form name="update" method="POST" action="msa_pauze_admin.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
<?php
                                    if (!empty($_POST['Active'])) {
                                        $interval_check = "UPDATE `msa_segmenti` SET `Active` = 0 ";
                                        $mysqli->query($interval_check);
                                    }
                                    $interval = $conn->query("SELECT ID,Vrsta_segmenta, Active FROM `msa_segmenti`");
                                    if ($interval->num_rows > 0) {
                                    while ($row = $interval->fetch_array()) {
                                        $id = $row["ID"];
                                        if (isset($_POST['Active'][$id])) {
                                            $interval_check = "UPDATE `msa_segmenti` SET `Active` = 1 WHERE `ID` = '" . $_POST['Active'][$id] . "'";
                                            $mysqli->query($interval_check);

                                        }
                                    }

                                        $interval = $conn->query("SELECT ID,Vrsta_segmenta, Active FROM `msa_segmenti`");
                                        while ($row = $interval->fetch_array()) {
//print_r($row);
                                            $checked = $row["Active"];
                                            $id = $row["ID"];
                                            //echo count($_POST['Active']);
                                            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit;

                                            ?>

        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><?php  echo $row["Vrsta_segmenta"]; ?></label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                    <div class="">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Active[<?php echo $id; ?>]"
                                                                   value="<?php echo $id; ?>"
                                                                   class="js-switch" <?php echo ($checked == 1) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                </div>



<?php

    }
} 

?>                              
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">Save</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `==` to set the value of variable. This operator is used for equal not for assign value.

Change from

```
$check_value == '1';
$check_value == '0';
```

Into

```
$check_value = '1';
$check_value = '0';
```

**2nd issue**

There is missing `>` near `<?php
                        } else if ($checked == '0')  "" 
                        ?>`

Comment: is this page is live somewhere? There must be error in HTML

Answer (score 0):

try this, Hope this will work

```
   if (isset($checked)) { ?> checked
                        <?php
                        } else {  "" 
                          }
                        ?>'
```

Note: this will work if you have 0 or 1 value in $checked variable
No need for elseif :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are unchecked, you will not get any value, so check the post data and write the code to match the behaviour, probably you will get null or empty,if unchecked.